# How to use pandas query() to correctly reference multiindex column headers in the query expression?

Tags: python, pandas

With a simple (single-level) column index one can access a column in a pandas DataFrame using .query() as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2),index=range(10),columns=['A','B'])
df1.query('A > 0.5')
```

I am struggling to achieve the analogous in a DataFrame with column multi-index:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2),index=range(10),columns=[['A','B'],['C','D']])
df2.query('(A,C) > 0.5') # fails
df2.query('"(A,C)" > 0.5') # fails
df2.query('("A","C") > 0.5') # fails
```

Is this doable?  Thanks...

(As to the motivation: query() seems to allow for very concise selection on a row mutli-index - column single-index dataframe, for example:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,2),index=[[0]*3+[1]*3,range(2,8)],columns=['A','B'])
df3.index.names=['one','two']
df3.query('one==0 & two<4 & A>0.5')
```

I would like to do something similar with a DF multi-indexed on both axes...)

Comment: MultiIndexing can be more trouble than it's worth. It can be really convenient when you need it, but you don't usually need it. If you want to use querying, I'm inclined to suggest you restructure your DataFrame.

Comment: I imagine this is a commonly encountered issue, I'm surprised this question was not more discoverable. #backlog

Answer (score 7):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13348) on github for this, but in the meantime, one suggested workaround is to refer to the column via the DataFrame variable through `@` notation:

```
df2.query("@df2.A.C > 0.5")
```

This is not a perfect workaround. If your header names/levels contain spaces, you will need to remove/rename them first.