# pandas:How to query multi-level column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Background:

When I do aggregate, I will sometimes end up with multi-level column dataframe, something like this:

[image]

so I need to query the data with multi-level columns.

Here is some dummy data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
columns=[('c','a'),('b','')]
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
df
```

[image]

My question: **how to query the data like `b > 0`, and `(c,a) > 0`?**

I tried`df.query("b > 0 ")`, `df.query("(c,a) > 0 ")`, but it returns `UndefinedVariableError: name 'b' is not defined`.

I also tried to search around, but didn't find things relevant, did I miss anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do this using the `.loc` indexer:

```
df[df[('c', 'a')] > 0]

   c  b
   a   
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df[df['b'] > 0]

   c  b
   a   
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: so I can't use `.query` for this?

Answer (score 3):

If we check the documentation, we can´t find any way to query a multilevel column:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

The lack of this implementation on query() is a known issue opened in Github since 2016:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13348

But there is a way to use query() for multindex column with the @ notation:

```
df.query("@df.b > 0 ")
df.query("@df.c.a > 0 ")
```

Note: credit also to this post:
[How to use pandas query() to correctly reference multiindex column headers in the query expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486501/how-to-use-pandas-query-to-correctly-reference-multiindex-column-headers-in-th)

Answer (score 3):

You can use backticks for this:

```
df.query("`('c', 'a')` > 0 & `('b', '')` > 0")
```

Comment: This is the way. Note that the column names have to be specified with single quotes; double quotes result in an error such as `KeyError: 'BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING__LPAR__DOUBLEQUOTE_c_DOUBLEQUOTE__COMMA___DOUBLEQUOTE_a_DOUBLEQUOTE__RPAR_'`